# Remove Items duplicate items from an array based on first entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, slice

I know it is easy to remove duplicate items from a list such as:

`lst = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'c' , 'd' , 'd' ]`

by using the method:

```
lst = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
#output
lst = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd']
```

However this method does not work if the list is made up of 2 element lists like this:

`lst = [['a','1'],['b','2'],['b','1'],['c','3'],['c','2']]`

I would like to remove all the entries where the first element is duplicated, leaving behind the first 
instance of each regardless of the second element. So the output should be:

```
lst = [['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates from whole list or just consecutive duplicates, eg. for `lst=[['a',1], ['b',2], ['a',2], ['a',3]]` the result would be `[['a',1], ['b',2], ['a',2]]`?

Comment: I want to remove any entry where the first element has already appeared in the list. So for your example the output should be [['a','1'],['b','2']]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools as it

# use the lambda to group by the first index
# next(g) returns the first instance of the group

[next(g) for k, g in it.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Result:

```
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

Comment: It's worth noting this requires `lst` to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
>>> lst = [['a','1'],['b','2'],['b','1'],['c','3'],['c','2']]
>>> dict(lst)
{'a': '1', 'b': '1', 'c': '2'}

>>> [k for k,_ in dict(lst).items()]
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> [[k,v] for k,v in dict(lst).items()]
[['a', '1'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '2']]
```

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Are you sure? The expected output clearly shows that the first pair should be kept.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Oh my bad. Who writes an example with increasing sequences and then just swap the last one just to trick others. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['b', '1'], ['c', '3'], ['c', '2']]

d = {}
for tupl in lst:
    first = tupl[0]
    if first not in d:
        d[first] = tupl

print(list(d.values()))
```

outputs:

```
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```